# How to timeOut a backgrounded task with NSTimer

Tags: ios, nstimer

I want to timeout a backgrounded task. I come with this naive block with timer approach.
It seams to work in debug mode, but the timer never got fired without the break point ??

Here below some pseudo code

```
- (void) processQueryWithCompletion:(void (^)( BOOL succeed, NSError *error, NSInteger nbItemProcessed )) completionHandler  timeOut:(NSTimeInterval) maxDuration {
    __block BOOL timerHasBeenFired=FALSE;
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 block:^{
        timerHasBeenFired=TRUE;
        completionHandler( FALSE, nil );
    } repeats:FALSE];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: ^( NSArray *objects, NSError *error ) {
        if (timerHasBeenFired) {
            return ;
        }

        [timer invalidate];


        //do stuff

        completionHandler( FALSE, nil );

    }];
}
```